# Adding page break to tables in Pages 5.5

Tags: macos, pages

In Pages 5.5 on Yosemite how can I add a page break into a table?

Answer (score 1):

You can't add a page break within a table. You can provide feedback to Apple regarding this:

- https://www.apple.com/feedback/pages.html

Answer (score 0):

You can make another table by copying your table format and paste another table on to the next page. Then you can continue the information. You can still reference the other table for formulas. Just Figured it out!